# Filtering one image with another one

Tags: c++, c, image, filtering

I have two images: [image: screnshot]

I want to produce a third one by combining the two in the following way:

One of the images (left) can be used as a template to remove 'artefacts' in the second image (middle). For example, considering the spot labeled as 1, it has a corresponding spot parter 2' in the middle image which is clean. As a result 2' should be preserved as intact as possible.
On the other hand, spot labeled as 2 has a main spot 2' in the middle image which is 'contaminated' by smaller spots (which are for my problem considered as artefacts, labeled with *). 
The result I'd like to achieve is shown in the RHS figure, where those artefacts have been removed.
I have the two images stored as floating point arrays (I'm using C++, but any other language should be fine).

I thought about using some morphologic technique (e.g. erosion / dilation), but with no luck so far. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post images here.  BTW: your links are not visible.

Comment: Also, show us what you've attempted to do in C/C++ so far, so that we have a baseline of how to modify/update your code.

Comment: I can see the image when clicking on the link 1. Does not work for you?

Comment: I no longer have the C++ code, what I tried was just a useless attempt and I did not commit it to our SVN repository.

Comment: "any other language should be fine"... lua? prolog? forth? pascal? ML? APL?

Comment: How did you decide the starred ones are artefacts? Is it the distance along the x-axis? What is the significance of the inner shapes in the left picture - I mean, why are they like "contours"

Comment: The starred ones are considered as artefacts by comparison with the left image: For each 'large' spot in the left image, there could only be one single spot in the middle image centered at the same coordinates as in the left image. Any other residual peak is an artefact produced by another signal processing algorithm.

Comment: So you find the centres of the blobs on the left, and then for each one, find the blob on the right that has the nearest centre. Which aspect is causing you trouble?